# Why I am facing the condition problem in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, cs50, credit-card

What is going wrong here? If I enter 4123456789098 then by dividing this number with 10^12 it should be equal to 4 but it is not?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    while (true)
    {
        long long int id = get_long("Number: ") ;
        int k = 0 ;
        while (id != 0)
        {
                id = id / 10 ;
                k++ ;
        }
        printf("%i\n", k) ;

        // VISA

        if (k == 13)
        {
            int x = id / pow(10 , 12) ;

            if (x == 4)
            {
                printf("VISA\n") ;
                break ;
            }

            else
            {
                printf("INVALID V\n") ;
            }
        }

        // AMEX

        else if (k == 15)
        {
            int y = id / pow(10 , 13) ;

            if (y == 34 || y == 37)
            {
                printf("AMEX\n") ;
                break ;
            }

            else
            {
                printf("INVALID A\n") ;
            }
        }

        // VISA or MASTERCARD

        else if (k == 16)
        {
            int z_M = id / pow(10 , 14) ;
            int z_V = id / pow(10 , 15) ;

            if (z_M >= 51 && z_V <= 55)
            {
                printf("MASTERCARD\n") ;
                break ;
            }

            else if (z_V == 4)
            {
                printf("VISA\n") ;
                break ;
            }

            else
            {
                printf("INVALID V or A\n") ;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Number: 4123456789098
13
INVALID V
```

Expected Output:

```
Number: 4123456789098
13
VISA
```

Comment: Are you ever going to add `1` to a credit card number? Divide by `23`? Multiply by `3`? No! Then it's not a number :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying the value of original `id` variable. Then when you are trying to find first digit with `int x = id / pow(10, 12)`. `x` will always be zero as `id` will always be zero. One thing you can do is to store the value of `id` in some temporary variable.
You can change this from

```
while (id != 0)
{
     id = id / 10 ;
     k++ ;
 }
```

to this:

```
long long temp = id;
while (temp != 0)
{
    temp = temp / 10 ;
    k++ ;
 }
```